# Cordova App issue

Tags: android, cordova

I ve build an app with Cordova and i have major issues with the app. I've use 'phonegap serve'in cmd  and i connect to server IT works properly but now when I've published the app IT won t work how IT should.,not even bg image loads.I've attached some images to see how IT should work and how IT works.The app name is Music Gather on google play store. [image][image]

Comment: Please debug your Android app with chrome://inspect and paste any error msg

Comment: Blink deferred a task in order to make scrolling smoother. Your timer and network tasks should take less than 50ms to run to avoid this. Please see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/rail and https://crbug.com/574343#c40 for more information.

Comment: Errors:https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at localStorage.js:2
animation.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at animation.js:2
style.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at style.js:1
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You got lots of 404 my friend, you should fix that 1st